# Pass current timestamp as a job parameter in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using spring batch, but due to job instance already exist error I need to add current time in my job parameter. I am unable to figure out where to add job parameters. Here is my code:

```
<step id="myStep">
 <tasklet>
  <chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor" writer="myWriter" commit-interval="6000" skip-limit="9000">
  //some more code.
 </chunk>
 </tasklet>
</step>

<bean id="myReader" class="org.springframework,batch.item.database.StoredProcedueItemReader" scope="step">
 //define property for datasource , procedurename , rowmapper, parameters
 <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="myPreparedStatmentSetter">
</bean>

<bean id="myPreparedStatmentSetter" class="com.mypackage.MyPreparedStatementSetter" scope="step">
 <property name="kId" value="#{jobParameters[kId]}">
</bean>
```

When I try to run the job for same `kId` multiple times I get `The job already exist` error, so I need to add current timestamp to my job parameter.
Would adding current time stamp as a property in the bean `myPreparedStatmentSetter` be sufficient, or do I need to add jobparameter somewhere else too?  From where exactly are jobparameters picked from in spring file?

In case I need to add timestamp to the bean here is a questions -My stored procedure takes only `kID` as paramter, I dont need to pass current time stamp to stored procedure, then why I need to add the same in `myPreparedStatmentSetter`.

Also how would I add current timestamp in an xml file without java code?

EDIT

Here is my jobLauncher bean

```
<bean Id= "jobLauncher "class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
 <property name="jobRepository" value="myJobRepo">
</bean>
```

Comment: jobParameter needs to be provided to joblauncher so tell more as how you launching the job. jobParameter  has nothing to do with step or reader configuration. Also, just a suggestion to use Java configuration instead of xml one.

Comment: @Sabir Khan I am using a CommandLineJobRunner

Answer (score 4):

Adding a "random" job parameter by hand, while it can work, isn't the most ideal way to get around the job instance already exists error.  Instead, you should consider adding a `JobParametersIncrementer` to your job.  Spring provides the `RunIdIncrementer` as an implementation of this out of the box.  A job configured with it would look something like the following:

```
@Bean
public Job myJob() { 
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                            .incrementer(runIdIncrementer())
                            .start(step1())
                            .build();
}

@Bean
public JobParametersIncrementer runIdIncrementer() {
    return new RunIdIncrementer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you already adding KId to your job parameters. Add following to your `joblaucher.run()` method.

```
new JobParametersBuilder()
.addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis())
.addLong("KId",<your KID>)
.toJobParameters();
```