# How to pass new Date to Spring Batch Tasklet in every new launch of Spring Batch Job?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

The example I am providing is simplified version of my code.

I am using `JobLauncher` to launch spring batch from `@Scheduled` method. My application never stops running because I am using `@Scheduled`

`import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;`

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000)
    public void scheduleFixedRate() { //launch job code }
```

I have a spring batch tasklet that uses date to do some logic. The issue is that my date never changes once initialized because `@Bean` is set when the application loads. The date never changes between run of spring batch job.

```
@Bean
public TestTasklet testTasklet(){

    final var tasklet = new TestTasklet();
    tasklet.setTextToLog(LocalDateTime.now().toString());

    return tasklet;
}
```

Is there a way to pass new Date to Spring Batch Tasklet in every new launch of Spring Batch Job? Few potential solutions, I thought of are below. I was wondering if there are better ways.

1. Generating new date inside `execute()` method of tasklet.
2. Setting `LocalDateTime` parameter value as job parameter value so values changes in every run.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477542/pass-current-timestamp-as-a-job-parameter-in-spring-batch?rq=1)

Comment: That is what `JobParameters` are for.

Comment: Yeah. I think I need to use `JobParameters`. Thanks for the responses.